# How to add custom build tags for docker images in azure-pipelines.yml file?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

We're using Azure DevOps for our project. I've `azure-pipelines.yml` file which uses the build id to the docker image tag. But, We're looking to manually add the docker image id as part of the build definition.

Is it possible to pass the runtime arguments from build queue rest api to azure-pipelines.yml file?

> azure-pipelines.yml

```
trigger:
 - master

pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

resources:
 - repo: self

variables:
  imageName: 'sampleapp1'
  dockerhubNS: 'kumaresh' 

steps:
 - task: Docker@2
   displayName: Login to Docker Hub
   inputs:
     command: login
     containerRegistry: dh-connection
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build and Push an image
  inputs:
    command: buildAndPush
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    containerRegistry: dh-connection
    repository: $(dockerhubNS)/$(imageName)
    tag: $(appBuildNumber)
```

> Request Body for Build Queue

```
"definition": {
    "id": Build_Definition_Id,
    "name": extractDefinitionName,
    "type": "build"
 },
 "templateParameters": {
     "tag": "1"
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean add build id manually?

Comment: You can create a variable and pass it to the tag using $(Your_Tag)

Comment: When I pass the env variable in tags, I get this error. ##[error]invalid argument "***.azurecr.io/project:$(dockertagvar)" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format.

Why it doesn't read the content of the variable?

Comment: @cell-in Can you try this `${{ parameters.tag }}` and pls refer the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to pass the runtime arguments from build queue rest api
>   to azure-pipelines.yml file?

Not sure what exactly mean about runtime argument. But I guess what you are looking for is queue build with rest api along with passing dynamic variable to pipeline at same time.

**Sample scenario:**

Here is my `azure-pipeline.yml`:

```
parameters:
- name: tag
  type: string
  default: 'aaa'

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: build
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: DockerHub
    repository: {my docker repos}
    command: build
    Dockerfile: Docker/TestWebApi/Dockerfile
    tags: '${{ parameters.tag }}'

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: push
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: DockerHub
    repository: {my docker repos}
    command: push
    tags: '${{ parameters.tag }}'
```

You can see, the dynamic image tag it needed is parameter `tag`. It will be passed a new value when I queue this pipeline with **rest api**:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{definition id}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

**Body:**

```
{
  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "refName": "refs/heads/master"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "tag": "new"
  }
}
```

Just configure the variable you want pass to in request body.

[image]

---

Added:

```
  "variables": {
    "myVariable": {
      "value": "0325ApiQueue"
    }
```

Comment: I'm using build queue api to run the build definition. How to add values in parameter attribute?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, do you mean  you defined the parameter attribute in your YAML pipeline?

Comment: Yes. I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1 to run the build definition. There is one option 'parameters'. Can we use to pass the tag number?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, of course sure. See my updating answer.

Comment: The `templateParameters` is same as `parameters` in `azure-pipelines.yml` file?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, yep! It used for pass parameters to YAML pipeline.

Comment: Lian - MSFT I could not able to get the values from the request body. It is automatically picks up the build id as the docker image tag like 40.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, how do you configure the tag in build definition? `$(Build.Buildid)`?

Comment: I didn't include this option in the request body. Do we need to configure `$(Build.Buildid)` in Build Queue REST API, right?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, `Build.Buildid` is a environment variable, you can not change and override that. You need configured it by using your customized variable if you want a customized value.

Comment: Can we define `Build.Buildid = ${{ parameters.tag }}` in `azure-pipelines.yml` file?

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, No, you can not. `Build.Buildid` is environment variable. We can not override that. Do you mind share your YAML, so that I can get more clear on that?

Comment: I've added YAML file contents in the question.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS I did not see you configured the parameters in your YAML. what you are using and assigned to tag is a variable, rather than a parameter. If it is a variable, you should use another format in body.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS, Check my added content, if what you are targeting is a variable, you should use that format to add a variable at queue time

Comment: I've tried with `POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1` REST API to start the build by passing the variable values but it didn't work. I replaced this API with `https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{definition id}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview.1` and it worked.

Comment: @KumareshBabuNS. Yeah, The previous api is work for pipeline that configured by UI. For YAML pipeline, you need use the second one, the one I ever shared in my answer. Awesome to know you have it succeed now!